# QtSerialPort has unavailable data, segmentation fault under Windows 8 only

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5, qtserialport

```
const QSerialPortInfo* serialPortInfo = nullptr;

bool PortManager::setPort(QString portName) {
    const QList<QSerialPortInfo> infoList = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();
    for (const QSerialPortInfo portInfo : infoList) {
        if (portInfo.portName() == portName && serialPortInfo != &portInfo) {
            serialPortInfo = &portInfo;
        }
    }
    if (serialPortInfo != nullptr) {
        if (portName != "" && serialPortInfo->isValid()) { //segmentation fault
            if (serialPort->isOpen()) {
                serialPort->close();
            }
            serialPort = new QSerialPort(*serialPortInfo, this);
            if (serialPort->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
                if (serialPort->clear()) {
                    if (serialPort->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud38400, QSerialPort::AllDirections)
                            && serialPort->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl)
                            && serialPort->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity)) {
                        isPortSet = true;
                    }
                    .
                    .
                    .
```

This is my code which works both on Linux and Windows 7. Now I'm testing it on Windows 8 and I'm getting segmentation fault on this->serialPortInfo->isValid() (and any other function of serialPortInfo). All the data of any specific QSerialPortInfo object is "unavailable" (as debugger states it) which seems to me that I don't have some priviliges to use them. On Linux, I had to be a member of uupc (if I recall correctly) group to not have such errors but on Windows 7 I didn't have to do a thing. I run Qt Creator "as Administrator" but it doesn't help; maybe I have to somehow tell it to run qmake as Administrator too? But it's just my guess, maybe the reason is different...

Comment: To nitpick a little, you do know that Windows don't have anything *named* "segmentation faults"?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: whatever it has, it's called "SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault" by Qt Creator; but I work on MinGW which is basically a Linux so... I don't really know much about Windows. ;-) Does it change anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical case of why Qt encourages you to use const reference in for loops when you do not plan to change the content. See this line:

```
for (const QSerialPortInfo portInfo : infoList) {
```

You ought to be writing this to make it work:

```
for (const QSerialPortInfo &portInfo : infoList) {
//                         ^
```

The reason is very simple, you are creating a temporary copy which get destroyed when going out-of-scope rather than using the original list item which will outlive the loop since the original list is outside.

You must be happy that it works at all on Linux and Windows 7. I am very surprised about that and even if it does, it might blow up at your customer at any certain moment.

That being said, your concept seems to be wrong overall. You query all the items to find one dedicated port. It would be much clearer to just construct your QSerialPortInfo instance in the first place like this:

```
serialPortInfo = new QSerialPortInfo(portName);
```

Moreover, you really ought to be using a stack object rather than heap. Info classes like that are not meant to be allocated on the heap, especially without smart pointer management.

It is also needless to say that making a global variable when they are evil is bad, especially in this case, where you could avoid it by putting that into the method itself.

You could also then get rid of the following line if you stop using a pointer:

```
if (serialPortInfo != nullptr) {
```

Not to mention, in a Qt application, you should be using Q_NULLPTR anyway, since that will also work without C++11 support, and the same reason goes to your original for loop. I would use foreach from Qt, but then again, I think the overall concept is wrong.

It seems that you do not even need a `QSerialPortInfo` instance since all you are using is just the name which you could pass directly to the `QSerialPort` object. Hence, you could get rid of even the `QSerialPortInfo` object.

Therefore, just drop the for loop and `QSerialPortInfo` instance altogether and use `QSerialPort` directly within the method is my suggestion.

Comment: I did what you have said so there was no QSerialPort instance or any loop but it caused only that segmentation fault started to appear on QSerialPort creation, not on QSerialPortInfo... but when I went further with your advices and changed pointers into real objects - the creation is fine but asking about serialPort.portName() is still causing segmentation faults. But this change revealed that there is another fault for some random timeout() signal further in the code... basically I feel like I will have to rewrite everything which is bad as EVERYTHING WAS FINE on Windows 7. :/

Comment: but I don't understand the reason behind that... for me, this code should work and it's working right now on my laptop... so there is no "mistake" there, right?

Comment: @smsware: there is undefined behavior with the reuse of an already destructed object. Like I wrote in the answer, I am surprised that it only blew up now.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this loop:

```
for (const QSerialPortInfo portInfo : infoList) {
    if (portInfo.portName() == portName && serialPortInfo != &portInfo) {
        serialPortInfo = &portInfo;
    }
}
```

The variable `portInfo` has its scope inside the loop only, and for the current iteration only. Once the loop iterates, that variable is destructed. Using a pointer to a destructed object is [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and the probable cause of your crashes.

My advice for you on how to stop it is to not use a pointer. Instead copy the structure.

Comment: Why not `const &` for `portInfo`?

Comment: @TemplateRex For that you have to ask the OP. The code I'm showing is a quote from the question to show what the problem is.

Comment: Well you could at least suggest him to avoid double cooy overhead.

Comment: @TemplateRex would that change anything? I mean I can see how it can be const w/o problem here but how is that any better? About this copy there, it was my attempt to create pointer and check if it's equal to serialPortInfo pointer (which is now not a pointer) as a opposite to (*serialPortInfo != portInfo); I didn't really think it's a difference there.

Comment: @smsware I think it's just always better to use `for(auto const& element : range)` than `for(auto const : range)`